# SDP Offer/Answer model with DTMF rtpmap/fmtp mismatch

Tags: sip, sdp, dtmf

Imagine an offer SDP that has one line of "m" with codecs 8 and 101 for DMTF and marked as sendrecv:

```
m = audio 35904 RTP/AVP 8 101
a = rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a = rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a = fmtp:101 0-15
a = sendrecv
```

The offered SDP is answered by a SDP with one line of "m" containing codecs 8 and 120 for DTMF similarly marked as sendrecv:

```
m = audio 1235 RTP/AVP 8 120
a = rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a = rtpmap:120 telephone-event/8000
a = fmtp:101 0-15
a = sendrecv
```

From [RFC 3264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264#section-6):

> For streams marked as sendrecv in the answer,    the "m=" line MUST
> contain at least one codec the answerer is willing    to both send and
> receive, from amongst those listed in the offer.    The stream MAY
> indicate additional media formats, not listed in the    corresponding
> stream in the offer, that the answerer is willing to    send or
> receive (of course, it will not be able to send them at this    time,
> since it was not listed in the offer).

Above part of the RFC3264, proves that sending a different DTMF fmtp(120 to 101) in answer SDP complies with RFC3264 since the codec 8(G711a) matches with the offer SDP.

**Is it okay to say the codec exchange is completed successfully and DTMF exchange will okay or is DTMF is not expected to work at this point?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In general:**

RTP payload type numbers 0-95 identify a static media encoding. E.g. payload type 8 means PCMA audio with a clock rate of 8000 Hz ([RFC3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#section-6)). As such, this description doesn't have to (but should) be included in the media format description of the SDP offer/answer, using the "a=rtpmap:" and "a=fmtp:" attributes ([RFC4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-5.14)).

Payload type numbers 96-127 are dynamic. These can be used to negotiate encodings that aren't included in the static list. When using one of these numbers, an encoding specification has to be included in the media format description to specify the exact encoding parameters.

Both negotiating parties can choose their own dynamic payload type number to represent the same media encoding, this doesn't have to be the same number. This can be useful when a party already assigned a particular dynamic payload type number to another encoding. In your example one party uses 101 in the m-line and the other one uses 120, but these numbers represent the same media encoding (see "a=rtpmap:" lines). Each party tells the other 'when you send RTP using encoding X you must include payload type number Y in the RTP packet headers.

The payload type number is included in the PT field of RTP packets headers ([RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.1))

**In this case**:

The "a=fmtp:" attribute in the answer specifies 101 as payload type number instead of 120. That means it doesn't apply to the telephone-events payload and no information is available as to which DTMF events are supported ([RFC 4733](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4733#section-2.4.1)). I think this is an implementation error and the fmtp attribute is meant to apply to the telephone-events payload.

It is an indication that you should expect DTMF issues. But it could also all work fine. Give it a try...